# LWC that is Overwriting PreChat from Embedded Service Deployment Look Really Strange

Tags: lightning-web-components, service-cloud-console

I have a LWC that is overriding PreChat Form on a Embedded Service Deployment.

The form functions and works great, but the LightningCombobox looks really weird inside the prechat form.

[image: Here you can see how the combobox looks nothing like a combobox]

[image: Even further when you hit 'Select An Option' or the down arrow it shows the options like so.]

I believe there is CSS on the website that where the Service Deployment is hosted at that is overriding or causing strange behaviors in my LWC.

```
<template>
<div if:true={hasFields}>
    <div class="formContent embeddedServiceSidebarForm">
        <div class="slds-var-p-around_medium">
            <template for:each={fields} for:item="field">
                <div key={field.name} class="slds-var-p-bottom_small">
                    <template if:true={field.isVisible}>
                        <template if:true={field.isPicklist}>
                            <lightning-combobox
                                name={field.name}
                                label={field.label}
                                value={field.value}
                                options={field.options}
                                required={field.required}
                                onchange={handleFieldChange}>
                            </lightning-combobox>
                        </template>
                        <template if:true={field.isTextArea}>
                            <lightning-textarea
                                name={field.name}
                                label={field.label}
                                value={field.value}
                                required={field.required}>
                            </lightning-textarea>
                        </template>
                        <template if:true={field.isText}>
                            <lightning-input 
                                name={field.name}
                                type="text"
                                label={field.label}
                                value={field.value}
                                required={field.required}>
                            </lightning-input>
                        </template>
                        <template if:true={field.isEmail}>
                            <lightning-input 
                                name={field.name}
                                type="email"
                                label={field.label}
                                value={field.value}
                                required={field.required}>
                            </lightning-input>
                        </template>
                        <template if:true={field.isPhone}>
                            <lightning-input 
                                name={field.name}
                                type="tel"
                                label={field.label}
                                value={field.value}
                                required={field.required}>
                            </lightning-input>
                        </template>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonWrapper embeddedServiceSidebarForm">
        <button type="button" onclick={handleStartChat}
            class="slds-button slds-button--neutral startButton uiButton--default uiButton embeddedServiceSidebarButton">
            <span class="label bBody">{Send}</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

That is my HTML

```
    :host {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
   }
 
lightning-button {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
 
.embeddedServiceSidebarForm.formContent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: var(--lwc-esColorBackgroundInverse,#fff);
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}
 
.embeddedServiceSidebarForm.buttonWrapper {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 24px 24px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) calc(100% - 77px), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}

.embeddedServiceSidebarButton .label, .embeddedServiceSidebarButton:disabled .label {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: var(--lwc-colorTextInverse,rgb(0, 0, 0));
}

lightning-input, lightning-textarea, lightning-combobox {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block !important;
}


lightning-combobox {
    display: block;
    
}

.slds-var-p-around_medium {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.slds-var-p-bottom_small {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    align-items: center;
}

.slds-form-element__label {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

That is my current CSS.

What is the cause of the strange look in the form? How can I fix it?